# Estimate total runtime of C++ function by measuring one iteration

Tags: c++, performance, time, runtime, cumulative-sum

I have implemented a c++ method that calculates the maximum ulp error between an approximation and a reference function on a given interval. The approximation as well as the reference are calculated as single-precision floating point values. The method starts with the low bound of the interval and iterates over each existing single-precision value within the range.

Since there are a lot of existing values depending on the range that is chosen, I would like to estimate the total runtime of this method, and print it to the user.

I tried to execute the comparison several times to calculate the runtime of one iteration. My approach was to multiply the duration of one iteration with the total number of floats existing in the range. But obviously the execution time for one iteration is not constant but depends on the number of iterations, therefore my estimated duration is not accurate at all... Maybe one could adapt the total runtime calculation in the main loop?

My question is: Is there any other way to estimate the total runtime for this particular case?

Here is my code:

```
void FloatEvaluateMaxUlp(float(*testFunction)(float), float(*referenceFunction)(float), float lowBound, float highBound)
{
    /*initialization*/
    float x = lowBound, output, output_ref;
    int ulp = 0;
    long long duration = 0, numberOfFloats=0;

    /*calculate number of floats between lowBound and highBound*/
    numberOfFloats = *(int*)&highBound - *(int*)&lowBound;

    /*measure execution time of 10 iterations*/
    int iterationsToEstimateTime = 1000;
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterationsToEstimateTime; i++)
    {
        printProgressInteger(i+1, iterationsToEstimateTime);
        output = testFunction(x);
        output_ref = referenceFunction(x);
        int ulp_local = FloatCompareULP(output, output_ref);
        if (abs(ulp_local) > abs(ulp))
            ulp = ulp_local;
        x= std::nextafter(x, highBound + 0.001f);
    }
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
    duration /= iterationsToEstimateTime;
    x = lowBound;
    


    /*output of estimated time*/
    std::cout <<std::endl<<std::endl<< " Number of floats: " << numberOfFloats << "   Time per iteration: " << duration << "  Estimated total time: " << numberOfFloats * duration << std::endl;
    std::cout << " Starting test in range [" << lowBound << "," << highBound << "]." << std::endl;


    long long count = 0;

    /*record start time*/
    t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    
    for (count; x < highBound; count++)
    {
        printProgressInteger(count, numberOfFloats);
        output = testFunction(x);
        output_ref = referenceFunction(x);
        int ulp_local = FloatCompareULP(output, output_ref);
        if (abs(ulp_local) > abs(ulp))
            ulp = ulp_local;
        x = std::nextafter(x, highBound + 0.001f);

    }

    /*record stop time and compute duration*/
    t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count();

    /*result output*/
    std::cout <<std::endl<< std::endl << std::endl << std::endl << "*********************************************************" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "                   RESULT                                " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*********************************************************" << std::endl;
    std::cout << " Iterations: " << count << "  Total execution time: " << duration << std::endl;
    std::cout << " Max ulp: " << ulp <<std::endl;
    std::cout << "*********************************************************" << std::endl;


}
```

Comment: To get a better estimate, you'll need more data.  Some of your thorns or roadblocks will be the task switching by the operating system.  Another could be the resolution of your clock or measuring device.  Remember, today's processor's are executing instructions in the nanosecond range.  If you run more iterations, you could get your measurements into something more reliable such as milliseconds or seconds.  Unfortunately, clocks have not kept up with this speed.  The other question is the resolution of the OS clock, the H/W clock may have finer resolution, but the OS clock may not.

Comment: In the embedded systems world, oscilloscopes and logic analyzers are used for profiling.  The code writes to a test point (or other device that the instrument can clip on to, such as an LED).  One is example is for the code to assert the test point at the start of the measurement, then deassert at the end of the measurement.  Usually these instruments have fine enough timing to measure one instruction.  More than one measurement would be taken, as an average, to eliminate outliers and noise.  We would go with the average of the samples from the instruments.

Comment: Since you probably don't have measuring instruments nor test points, you'll need to run at least 1E06 iterations, between the clock measurements, to get a meaningful average.  Again, you want to eliminate outliers and noise from the operating system.  In statistics, one sample is never enough.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! You are right, I neither have measuring Instruments nor Test points, that is no possibility. So am I right assuming that you would recommend to set iterationsToEstimateTime to 1e6 to eliminate noise etc?

Comment: As they say with statistics, the more data, the better quality of an average.